# Forging X events, I'm looking for server time

Tags: c, xlib

I'm writing a window manager and I need to send an XCrossingEvent to my window that gets focus. Is there a way to forge an event without doing it manually? If there isn't they only crossing event structure variable I have trouble with is the time stamp- how do you get the server-time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very comfortable about this answer, but I usually set the timestamp field to zero. What little code I've seen that interprets the timestamp, treats zero broadly to mean "now". So far this has worked out OK, although I accept that it is sub-optimal.